# Java - Operator does not equal not working in a if condition for strings

Tags: java, string, if-statement, conditional-statements, equals

I have the following code for Java (Android) in a switch case check. I have set the default condition to the following code:

```
 switch (value_gain_array[0]) {

        case 5: 
    column[1][0] = "4";
    column[1][1] = "3";
    column[1][2] = "1";
        break;

        case 10:
    column[1][0] = "4";
    column[1][1] = "5";
    column[1][2] = "1";
    break;

        case 50:
    column[1][0] = "1";
    column[1][1] = "1";
    column[1][2] = "4";
break;
        case 100:
    column[1][0] = "2";
    column[1][1] = "3";
    column[1][2] = "5";
break;
        case 500: 
    column[1][0] = "3";
    column[1][1] = "2";
    column[1][2] = "2";
break;
        case 1000:
    column[1][0] = "4";
    column[1][1] = "4";
    column[1][2] = "1";
break;
        case 100000:
    column[1][0] = "5";
    column[1][1] = "5";
    column[1][2] = "3";
    break;

        case 222:
    column[1][0] = "4";
    column[1][1] = "1";
    column[1][2] = "1";
    break;

    case 999:
    column[1][0] = "4";
    column[1][1] = "2";
    column[1][2] = "1";
    break; 

        default:
            boolean control = false;
            while (control == false) {
    //column[1][0] = Integer.toString(Generate_Random_15());
    //column[1][1] = Integer.toString(Generate_Random_15());
    //column[1][2] = Integer.toString(Generate_Random_15());
                column[1][0] = "2";
                column[1][1] = "3";
                column[1][2] = "5";

    String control_column = column[1][0] + column[1][1] + column[1][2];

    if (!"431".equals(control_column) || !"451".equals(control_column) || !"114".equals(control_column) || !"235".equals(control_column) || !"322".equals(control_column) || !"441".equals(control_column) || 
            !"553".equals(control_column) || !"411".equals(control_column) || !"421".equals(control_column)) { control = true;}
        }
            Toast.makeText(context, "control_column_0[]+   " + column[1][0]+column[1][1]+column[1][2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
    }
```

Unfortunatly the if condition of the default switch is not working, even when I force the value control to be false like in the following case "235", it never happens. The following if condition should create an infinite loop (of course, the real purpose is to use random generator check instead) What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you,

Pierre

```
    boolean control = false;
            while (control == false) {
    //column[1][0] = Integer.toString(Generate_Random_15());
    //column[1][1] = Integer.toString(Generate_Random_15());
    //column[1][2] = Integer.toString(Generate_Random_15());
                column[1][0] = "2";
                column[1][1] = "3";
                column[1][2] = "5";

    String control_column = column[1][0] + column[1][1] + column[1][2];

    if (!"431".equals(control_column) || !"451".equals(control_column) || !"114".equals(control_column) || !"235".equals(control_column) || !"322".equals(control_column) || !"441".equals(control_column) || 
            !"553".equals(control_column) || !"411".equals(control_column) || !"421".equals(control_column)) control = true;
        }
            Toast.makeText(context, "control_column_0[]+   " + column[1][0]+column[1][1]+column[1][2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
break;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if i understand your problem. Do you want control to be true, if you have 235 or not?

Comment: No, I want control to be false if 235

Comment: So if control has the value of one of the strings in that if, it should be false, otherwise it should be true, right?

Comment: The purpose of the default condition is to generate random numbers which are NOT 431 451 114 235 322 etc

Comment: Yes, exactly dunni

Comment: Thanks very much dunni for your help

Comment: Consider `a != 1 || a != 2`, you can see that no matter what value you have for `a` this will always be true. SImiarly `a == 1 && a == 2` you would expect to always be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `control` to the value `true`, if the control number is not any of the values mentioned in your if condition, you have to connect the values with the logical AND:

```
if (!"431".equals(control_column) && !"451".equals(control_column) && !"114".equals(control_column) && !"235".equals(control_column) && !"322".equals(control_column) && !"441".equals(control_column) && 
        !"553".equals(control_column) && !"411".equals(control_column) && !"421".equals(control_column)) control = true;
```